# Having Trouble Running biocLite()

Tags: r, bioconductor

Following instructions from this website: https://www.bioconductor.org/install/ I first run

```
 source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
```

It runs fine, and I get the following output.

```
Bioconductor version 3.6 (BiocInstaller 1.28.0), ?biocLite for help
```

Following the above installation guide I try to then run the next command.

```
biocLite()
```

This produces an error.

```
* installing *source* package ‘BiocGenerics’ ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Creating a new generic function for ‘append’ in package ‘BiocGenerics’
Creating a new generic function for ‘as.data.frame’ in package ‘BiocGenerics’
Creating a new generic function for ‘cbind’ in package ‘BiocGenerics’
Error : identical(as.call(parse(text = old_code)[[1L]]), body[[7L]][[3L]]) is not TRUE
Error in apply_hotfix73465(getGeneric("cbind")) : hotfix failed for generic function cbind()
Error : unable to load R code in package ‘BiocGenerics’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘BiocGenerics’
* removing ‘/home/jrisi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/BiocGenerics’
ERROR: dependency ‘BiocGenerics’ is not available for package ‘S4Vectors’
* removing ‘/home/jrisi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/S4Vectors’
ERROR: dependency ‘BiocGenerics’ is not available for package ‘Biobase’
* removing ‘/home/jrisi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Biobase’
ERROR: dependencies ‘BiocGenerics’, ‘S4Vectors’ are not available for package ‘IRanges’
* removing ‘/home/jrisi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/IRanges’
ERROR: dependencies ‘BiocGenerics’, ‘Biobase’, ‘IRanges’, ‘S4Vectors’ are not available for package ‘AnnotationDbi’
* removing ‘/home/jrisi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/AnnotationDbi’
```

Here is the output from sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 17.10

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
[3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] BiocInstaller_1.28.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2 tools_3.4.2
```

I found this post where another user seemed to run into a similar issue, but it doesn't appear as if the error was ever resolved. I would prefer to not have to download the patched version of R if possible. But if that is what i must do, then so be it. https://support.bioconductor.org/p/101833/#101893

Additionally, I tried running R using --vanilla, and it didn't fix the issue.

EDIT: Looking at the post where someone had a similar issue https://support.bioconductor.org/p/101833/#101893, I followed the instructions of someone at the bottom where they recommended I run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install r-bioc-biocgenerics
```

And this worked! Although I does not seem like a permanent solution since I will have to manually update in the future (I think).